# CentOs7: HugePages_Rsvd equals 18446744073709551615

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, centos7, huge-pages, dpdk

I have an application which uses a large amount of huge pages, for the purpose of [DPDK](http://dpdk.org/). I allocate the pages at system start and then load/unload the application several times.
After some reloads, the program cannot allocate huge pages anymore. When I look at [`meminfo`](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-meminfo.html), I see:

```
HugePages_Total:    2656
HugePages_Free:     1504
HugePages_Rsvd:     18446744073709551615   
HugePages_Surp:        0
```

This will remains this way, and will not let any application allocate huge pages, until I reboot the machine.

Any idea?

Comment: I presume there's some significance in the fact that that's exactly 2**64-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decrement_hugepage_resv_vma function attempts -1 for resv_huge_pages, 
but unsigned arithmetic causes it to instead ULONG_MAX (unsigned long resv_huge_pages), which is 18446744073709551615 on 64-bit systems.

```
alloc_huge_page()
    page = dequeue_huge_page_vma(h, vma, addr, avoid_reserve)
        decrement_hugepage_resv_vma() {
            h->resv_huge_pages--;
        }

static void return_unused_surplus_pages(struct hstate *h,
                    unsigned long unused_resv_pages)
{
    h->resv_huge_pages -= unused_resv_pages;
}
```

Other less odds reason is gather_surplus_pages() function can overflow resv_huge_pages.

Try next during you test:

```
while [  1  ] ; do date | awk '{print $4}' >> HugePages_Rsvd.log; cat /proc/meminfo | grep HugePages_Rsvd >> HugePages_Rsvd.log; sleep 1;  done
```

I gues if resv_huge_pages will increment slowly so problem in h->resv_huge_pages += delta;

But if resv_huge_pages suddenly become -1 (unsigned long == 18446744073709551615 ) so problem in h->resv_huge_pages--; (resv_huge_pages was 0 and aftre decrement == -1)

Depend from you kernel you can check patch
mm: numa: disable change protection for vma(VM_HUGETLB)
6b79c57b92cdd90853002980609af516d14c4f9c
and [BUG large value for HugePages_Rsvd](https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/6/19/227)

Comment: Thanks! So do you think this problem can be related to the patch suggested in the link you sent? I didn't understand exactly what application behavior can cause this error.

Comment: Debugging will show. Try cat /proc/ + app than ftrace. The best way rebuild kernel with you debugging info.